# How to convert this query using Spring Mongodb Aggregation apis?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

this is the query I want to perform:

```
db['applications'].aggregate(
 {$project: {key:1, _id:0}}
 ,{$group: { _id:null, keyList: {$addToSet:"$key"}}} );
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
 Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            project("key"),
            group("key").addToSet("key").as("keylist")
    );
```

However, the result produced is this:

```
Executing aggregation: 
{ "aggregate" : "applications" , "
  pipeline" : [ 
 { "$project" : { "key" : "$key"}} , 
 { "$group" : { "_id" : "$key" , "keylist" : { "$addToSet" : "$key"}}}
]}
```

Why is the _id key in the group set to the arguments of 'group'. How do I make it null?
How do i get Spring MongoData to produce the query I want?

Comment: FYI: This isn't directly related to your question, but you don't need to explicitly add the $project phase before the $group. MongoDB will automatically determine which fields are needed from the source document and only extract those. (I'm the main dev on the aggregation framework)

Comment: Just out of curiousity have that helped my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for the group phase you cannot pass null look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/).

```
public static GroupOperation group(String... fields)
Creates a new GroupOperation for the given fields.
Parameters:
fields - must not be null.
Returns:
```

However you can achive the same with selecting a field name for the group id which is not exists in the collection. Not beautiful but should work.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            project("key"),
            group("ANYSTRINGWHICHISNOTFIELDNAME").addToSet("key").as("keylist")
    );
```

You do not have to care about the project phase it is good to have smaller data in the pipeline but the result will be the same this way.

Comment: didn't work with spring data mongo 1.10.8.RELEASE, so using empty group() instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method taking a `String...` and simply pipe in no arguments:

```
group().addToSet("key").as("keylist")
```

In the currently released version this renders as:

```
$group: { _id : {}, keyList : { $addToSet : "$key" }}
```

While this is not 100% in line with the documentation it does the same as `_id : null`. We've filed and fixed [DATAMONGO-759](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-759) which will ship in 1.3.2 and 1.4 M1 of Spring Data Commons.

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of Spring Data MongoDB if you do not specify parameters to group it will group by null.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            project("key"),
            group().addToSet("key").as("keylist")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Didnt work for me , BUT what did work is to declare in you collection dummy property like  this:

```
Class Model{
...
...
private Integer dummyNotExistsProp
}
```

and then this is stupid query without matchin and projection but just to demonstrate the solution to the problem:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(Aggregation.group("dummyNotExistsProp").count().as("totalobjs"));
```